# Can you easily make an edge loop go through a triangle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, topology, loop

Is there any way to do something similar to Maya's insert edge loop tool, where the edge loop wraps around the triangle? (Using Ctrl + R makes the edge loop stop before the triangle)

[image]

Comment: I don't think this function is built in, but I guess you could always *Knife Project* an edge through the mesh.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the knife tool but I was looking for something more convenient, like this Maya tool so you can do all of the steps in one place.

Comment: Knife project is a little different from the knife tool, you can define a shape and then use that shape to cut all the way through something with respect to the current camera view (ortho or perspective)

Comment: I see. That's also a great alternative

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

1. In wireframe mode you can select easily all the edges what you want to cut at once.
2. To create the new loop on them select Edge>>Subdivide.
3. Now you can adjust the number of cuts on the bottom-left.
4. If you want to move them, select a loop and double hit "G".
5. To create more loops after the move, select a loop and choose
   Edge>>Bevel Edges.

Comment: Great! Thanks =)